# Specify indexName and type of index in elasticsearch in a properties file

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm using elasticsearch and spring in my application. For each index type, I have a document mapping. Using `@Document` annotation I have specified the `indexName` and `type` of index. For eg: `@Document(indexName = "myproject", type = "user")`. But for writing unit tests, I would want to create indexes with a different indexName. Hence I want the indexName to be read from a properties file. How to do this in spring?

Comment: I could not find an elegant solution for this. As a workaround, I just created a test class which extended the user class and specified the indexName for this test class separately.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by just using SPeL. It allows you to set a expression that Spring will parse at compile time. Hence allowing the Annotations to be processed during the compilation.

```
@Document(collection = "#{@environment.getProperty('index.access-log')}")
public class AccessLog{
    ...
}
```

Before Spring 5.x:

Note that there is no `@` in the SPeL.

```
@Document(collection = "#{environment.getProperty('index.access-log')}")
public class AccessLog{
    ...
}
```

Also I found that Spring also supports a much simpler Expression `@Document(collection = "${index.access-log}")` but I had mixed results with this.

After setting up the annotation as above you can use either

`application.properties`

```
index.access-log=index_access
```

or `application.yaml`

```yaml
index  :
  access : index_access
```

Answer (score -2):

Just use ElasticSearchTemplate from your unit tests to create the index with a different name and then use the method "index" or "bulkIndex" to index a document into the new index you just created.

```
    esTemplate.createIndex(newIndexName, loadfromFromFile(settingsFileName));
    esTemplate.putMapping(newIndexName, "user", loadfromFromFile(userMappingFileName));

    List<IndexQuery> indexes = users.parallelStream().map(user -> {
        IndexQuery index = new IndexQuery();
        index.setIndexName(newIndexName);
        index.setType("user");
        index.setObject(user);
        index.setId(String.valueOf(user.getId()));
        return index;
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
    esTemplate.bulkIndex(indexes);

    //Load file from src/java/resources or /src/test/resources
    public String loadfromFromFile(String fileName) throws IllegalStateException {
         StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(2048);
         try {
            InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream(fileName);
            LineNumberReader reader = new LineNumberReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            while (reader.ready()) {
               buffer.append(reader.readLine());
               buffer.append(' ');
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("couldn't load file " + fileName, e);
        }
        return buffer.toString();
    }
```

This should work as its working for me. Same scenario.

Comment: Does your answer mean "just don't use the @Document annotation" or does it mean something else ?

Comment: @Tristan correct. Dont use the Document annotation.

Comment: Well, I think u should check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33069670/spring-data-elasticsearch-document-indexname-defined-at-runtime/38530650#38530650