# Spring Data Elasticsearch @Document indexName defined at runtime

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

Is it possible to specify dynamically (at runtime) the `indexName` for each `@Document`, for example, via a configuration file? Or is it possible to make `@Document` Spring environment (dev, prod) dependant?

Thank you!

Comment: Also need some environment / profile based solution. Index name hardwired into annotation is not best option ...

Comment: I was trying to do the same using something similar to when you use @Value, but no luck yet. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31829456/inject-spel-parameter-on-annotation-parameter-like-what-is-done-with-value-on)  for more info.

Comment: You cant use @Value in this way because its not a bean managed/created by Spring but by you using new MyBean() . I still cant get idea behind this annotation settings. Everybody must deal with this for example when using diffent indexName for dev and prod. How do you do this?

Comment: @DavidMarko, at this point I am wondering if anybody reached production with spring-data-elasticsearch... Does anyone know an example?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The @Document annotation does not permit to pass the indexname in parameter directly. However I found a work around.

In my configuration class I created a Bean returning a string. In this string I injected the name of the index with @Value :

```
@Value("${etrali.indexname}")
private String indexName;

@Bean
public String indexName(){
    return indexName;
}
```

Afterward it is possible to inject the index into the @Documentation annotation like this :

```
@Document(indexName="#{@indexName}",type = "syslog_watcher")
```

It works for me, I hope it will help you.

Best regards

Comment: Thanks, in fact, it's the [SpEL](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/expressions.html) solution

Comment: Where did you register you `Bean`? I did so in the `@Configuration` annotated `ElasticsearchConfig` class. Apparently I still get an `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

The solution from Bruno probably works but the "I created a Bean returning a string" part is a bit confusing.

Here is how I do it :

- Have the "index.name" key valued in an application.properties file loaded by "`<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties" />`"
- Create a bean named ConfigBean annotated with `@Named` or `@Component`

```
    @Named
    public class ConfigBean {

      @Value("${index.name}")
      private String indexName;

      public String getIndexName() {
        return indexName;
      }

      public void setIndexName(String indexName) {
        this.indexName = indexName;
      }      

    }
```

- Inject the value of configBean.getIndexName() into the "@Document" annotation using Spring EL : `@Document(indexName = "#{ configBean.indexName }", type = "myType")`

P.S. : You may achieve the same result directly using the implicit bean "systemProperties" (something like #{ systemProperties['index.name'] }) but it didn't work for me and it's pretty hard to debug since u can't resolve systemProperties in a programmatic context (https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-6651)

Comment: I do not know how made this work, but "@Named" cannot be applied on Classes, and "@Configuration" did not make the indexName discoverable

Comment: Well, maybe your "@Named" can't, but my javax.inject.Named can.

Answer (score 2):

The Bruno's solution works but there is no need to create a new Bean in this way. What I do is:

- create a bean annotated with `@org.springframework.stereotype.Service` where the index name is loaded from the database:

```java
@Service
public class ElasticsearchIndexConfigService {

    private String elasticsearchIndexName;

    // some code to update the elasticsearchIndexName variable

    public String getIndexName() {
        return elasticsearchIndexName;
    }
}
```

- call the getIndexName() method from the bean in the `@Document` annotation using the SpEL:

```java
@Document(indexName = "#{@elasticsearchIndexConfigService.getIndexName()}", createIndex = false)
public class MyEntity {

}
```

The crucial part is to use `@` - `#{elasticsearchIndexConfigService.getIndexName()}` won't work. I lost some time to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

**This Worked for me**
application.properties

`index.prefix=test`

then use this code

`@Document(indexName = "#{@environment.getProperty('index.prefix')}")`