# Spring data elasticsearch to create index dynamically based on request parameter, percolator support and create index via Elasticsearch Operations

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I read through https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#reference to begin with

**My requirements**

1. I want to use percolator. Is there any support for it in spring data elasticsearch? I don't see any in the above link although I understand that percolating is same as indexing (technically from using spring data elasticsearch's perspective). So I can use the indexing part of spring data elasticsearch but just checking if there are any that are specific to percolator.
2. I want to create an index dynamically. I do understand I can achieve that using SpEL template expression as mentioned in  https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.mapping.meta-model.annotations but my case is slightly different, I will get the index name via the RequestParam as part of the API call. So this means as of my knowledge I cannot use SpEL or try something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/33520421/4068218
3. I see I can use ElasticsearchOperations or ElasticsearchRepository to create Index. Because of #2 (i.e index name via request parameter) I think ElasticsearchOperations better suits but I see IndexOperations facilitating createMapping, createSettings but not both together. I see putMapping too but I dont see anything that says both mapping and settings. The reason I want both is I want to create something like below to begin with

> ```
>   "settings" : {
>                 "index" : {
>                   "number_of_shards" : 1,
>                   "number_of_replicas" : 0
>                 }
>               },
>             "mappings": {
>                 "properties": {
>                   "message": {
>                     "type": "text"
>                   },
>                   "query": {
>                     "type": "percolator"
>                   }
>                 }
>               }
> ```

**Bottom line :**- How do I create an index (name of the index will be dynamic via request param) with mappings, settings using ElasticsearchOperations?
Any lead/help is much appreciated

Comment: `IndexOperations.createWithMapping()` which creates an index with settings and mappings in one call is available since the current version 4.2.0

Comment: @P.J.Meisch - Thanks for the response and your time. Since I want the index name to be dynamic (i.e I am accepting as a parameter in the API end point) I wont be able to use any class that will need  @Document(indexName = "name-of-the-index").

Comment: `elasticsearchOperations.indexOps(IndexCoordinates.of("whatever-indexname-you-need")).create(settings, mapping)`

Answer (score 0):

First of all thank you very much @P.J.Meisch. Upvoted both your comments as a token of gratitude.

Below worked for me. Below might help others in future

```
 Document mapping = Document.create().fromJson("{\n" +
                "\n" +
                "    \"properties\": {\n" +
                "      \"message\": {\n" +
                "        \"type\": \"text\"\n" +
                "      },\n" +
                "      \"query\": {\n" +
                "        \"type\": \"percolator\"\n" +
                "      }\n" +
                "    }\n" +
                "\n" +
                "}");
 Map<String, Object> settings = ImmutableMap.of( "number_of_shards" ,2,"number_of_replicas",1);
 elasticsearchOperations.indexOps(IndexCoordinates.of("whatever-indexname-you-need")).create(settings,mapping);
```

Comment: This helped me a lot, so thank you! As a side note, I think it's better to use `Document.from(Map)` than using a stringified JSON